# Grail domain model associations default sorting on multiple fields

Tags: sorting, grails, default, grails-orm

Ive searched around for a solution on sorting an domain models association on multiple field but not found a single answer.
Is this not feature not yet implemented and in that case is there a 'good' workaround

I have two models:

```
Board{
  static hasMany = [tiles: Tile]
  static mapping = {
     This is what i would like to do!!
    sort x : 'asc'
    sort y : 'acs'
  }
} 
Tile {
  int x
  int y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable if there is a sorting built into the mapping. I been working with Grails for almost 3 years, and have not seen that yet. But i think the easier way to do that is try using collection sort, and Title implements comparable. And you do a Collection.sort(tiles);